# Get date/times between two Moment date/times

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am using Node.JS and the excellent Moment library. I have a function that needs to generate an agenda of future dates (like an appointment system)

I have two timestamps representing the start and end of a period of time.

I want to create an array of date/times between these two times, dependent on a specific day and time of that day.

An example would be:

```
START DATE: 2019-01-26 15:00:01 (Saturday)
END DATE: 2019-02-23 15:00:00 (also a Saturday)
WE NEED: EVERY SATURDAY @ 1500

EXPECTED ARRAY:

2019-02-02 15:00:00
2019-02-09 15:00:00
2019-02-16 15:00:00
2019-02-23 15:00:00
```

Please note: The start is not included in the array because it is later (by one second) than what we are looking for.

Any idea on how to accomplish this in Node?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've created the the two start and ends as moment objects, then I set a third to the specific day and time I am looking for. But, looping through each period of 24 hours doesn't seem to produce anything. Most likely because my start and end times DO NOT match the target time I am looking for. I am simply trying to get the instances of a specific day/time between two timestamps. I was thinking of looping over every second between the two dates and making a comparison but I think that's just a horrible hack. I want to do it properly, but can't seen to find a method in the moment library to help.

Comment: Here's my take: https://codesandbox.io/s/6yjy525nxn

Answer (score 0):

```
const moment = require('moment')
const formatDate = date => moment(date).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')

const START_DATE = '2019-01-26 15:00:00'
const END_DATE = '2019-02-23 15:00:00'

let current = formatDate(START_DATE)
const end = formatDate(END_DATE)
let days = 7

let result = []
while (current > end) {
  current = moment(START_DATE).add(days, 'days')
  current = formatDate(current)
  result.push(current)
  days += 7
}
result.push(end)

result.forEach(date=>console.log(date))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import moment from 'moment';

const getDaysBetween = (startDate, endDate, day, time) => {


  // Define a first day of result

  let firstDay = moment(startDate)
  .day(day)
  .set('hour', time.match(/[\d]+(?=:)/g)[0])
  .set('minutes', time.match(/(?<=:)[\d]+/g)[0])
  .set('seconds', 0);

  let resultDates = [ firstDay ];


  // Add the rest

  let weekBetweenThese = endDate.diff(firstDay, 'week');

  Array(weekBetweenThese).fill({}).forEach((d, i) => {
    resultDates.push(moment(firstDay).add(i + 1, 'weeks'))
  });


  // Filter out somecase that result day match with startDate & endDate but time condition goes wrong

  resultDates = resultDates.filter(resultDate =>
    startDate <= resultDate &&
    resultDate <= endDate
  );

  return resultDates.map(resultDate => resultDate.toDate());
  // return resultDates; // Return array of moment date.

};

console.log(
  getDaysBetween(
    moment('2019-01-26 15:00:01'),
    moment('2019-02-23 15:00:00'),
    'Saturday', '15:00'
  )
)
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/wkpz72mo9w